# AWS RDS connection from localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to a RDS database (used alongside Elastic Beanstalk) from PGAdmin. From the "Connectivity & security" tab on the db dashboard, I selected the VPC security group and then edited the inbound rules to include a new rule of type "All traffic" with "My Ip" as the source. But adding my ip to the inbound rules does nothing, I keep getting timeout: expired on PGAdmin.

From what I can see on other questions & answers, this seems to be the only required configuration to change, however it does not solve the problem for me.

Does anyone experienced this? What do I need to do to connect to the database from PGAdmin?

Comment: You surely don't have the RDS in public subnet(no connectivity to the internet). You can check if that's the case. If yes, you won't be able to connect directly to your RDS from localhost. You will need a server in the middle.

Comment: Does it have a public IP?

Comment: Was the Amazon RDS database launched with `Publicly Accessible = Yes`?

Comment: Currently, Publicly accessible is "No". That explains it, right? Even if I add my Ip pr 0.0.0.0 @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Correct. If it is set to `Publicly Accessible = No` then the DNS name of the database will resolve to a **private IP address**, which is not accessible from the Internet even if the Security Groups are correctly configured. You can 'Modify' the database to turn it on. Also, the database will need to have been launched in a **public subnet** to be accessible.